# How to update edits in DataGridView to table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, oledb

I have bound a DataGridView to an SQL Server table in a .Net 5.0 WinForms project. Displaying the data works well.

I would like to update editions to the database as soon as I move to another row in the DataGridView. But I have not found a way to do this.
The solution presented [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12846/Auto-Saving-DataGridView-Rows-to-a-SQL-Server-Data?fid=261351&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&view=Normal&prof=True) seems not to work with an OleDbDataAdapter. The Update method does not accept a DataRow. Examples in [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.update?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_Common_DbDataAdapter_Update_System_Data_DataSet_System_String_) require a DataSet which I try to avoid. Other examples use a button to save changes.

The data gets loaded like this:

```
var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQueryString, connString);
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);                // fill data table from SQL server
var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.PositionChanged += new System.EventHandler(bindingSource_PositionChanged);
bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;       // connect binding source to data table
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;    // connect DataGridView to binding source
```

For the update I finally have tried this:

```
private void bindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dataRow = ((DataRowView)((BindingSource)sender).Current).Row;
    if (dataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)  // this is successful
    {
        dataAdapter.Update(dataRow);    // compile error
    }
}
```

I get the compile error

> Cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'System.Data.DataRow[]'.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Your DB provider objects are very powerful.  If you declare them at the form level so they persist, you can configure them so that you just `Update()` the DataAdapter and all pending changes are applied.  There is also no need to track movements and update 1 row at a time - the Datatable can store many, many differenct changes.

Comment: DataAdapter.Update cannot have a parameter of type DataRow. You need to pass an array of DataRow so just change to _dataAdapter.Update(new [] {dataRow});_

Comment: On a side note, consider using the `SqlClient` managed driver instead of `OleDb`.

Comment: @Ňɏssa Actually, I have declared them in the UserControl which contains the DataGridView. I have just patched the lines together so that I don't need to publish the whole solution. I prefer not to move it to the Form level. The UserControl should be autonomous.

Comment: @Steve This might be the direction - thanks. I have assigned the row to an array as the only element and passed that array to Update. It runs without error but doesn't update the database. When I move back to the edited row, I get the error: "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows." Any suggestion?

Comment: @Dan Thank you for the hint. The SQLDataAdapter is not available for .NET 5.0. It was difficult for me as a newcomer to decide what system to use. So I ended up with OleDb.

Comment: @Stringeater, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter` is available for .NET Core as part of the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/). The `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace objects are preferred for SQL Server data access in .NET Core nowadays.

Comment: @ Dan, Thank you, I have found it. I'll give it a try which will take time.

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter is successfully installed. Viewing the data works. But updating edits results in the same error as with OleDb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the 2 missing lines:

```
private SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;   // on UserControl level
commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);    // when loading data
```

A book has helped me: Michael Schmalz, C# Database Basics, O'Reilly

It is strange that the DOCS reference of SqlDataAdapter doesn't mention the SqlCommandBuilder.

Thanks to everybody who has spent precious time for a New contributor.

Answer (score 3):

### MVVM

In modern programming, there is the tendency to separate the model from the view. This separation makes it easier to change the way that your data is displayed without having to change your model. You can also change parts of the model without having to change the display. It is easier to reuse the model and to unit test it without having to start a forms program.

In WPF this separation between model and view is almost enforced. When using winforms you have to take care that you do not mix them more than needed.

To keep these two separated, adapter code is needed to glue your model to your view. This adapter code is quite often called the viewmodel. the abbreviation of these three is quite often called MVVM. Consider to familiarize yourself with the ideas of MVVM.

### Use a BindingList in your DataSource

If you want to separate your model from your view, you need methods to fetch the data that must be displayed from the database, and data to update items.

I don't know what you will be displaying in your DataGridView, but let's assume it is a sequence of Products, something like this:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string ProductCode {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

You will have methods to fetch the Products that must be displayed, and to Update one Product, or maybe several Products at a time:

```
IEnumerable<Product> FetchProductsToDisplay(...)
{
    // TODO: fetch the products from the database.
}

void UpdateProduct(Product product) {...}
void UpdateProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products) {...}
```

Implementation is out of scope of this question. By the way, did you notice, that because I put fetching and updating data in separate procedures, I hid where the Products are saved? It can be in an SQL server, but if you want it could also be a CSV or XML file, or even a dictionary, which could be handy for unit tests.

Besides: you can unit tests these methods without using your forms.

Using the visual studio designer you have added the columns and defined which column should show which Product property. You could also have done this in the constructor using property [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn?view=net-5.0)

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    this.columnProductCode.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.ProductCode);
    this.columnName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
    ...
}
```

You don't need to set the DataPropertyName for properties that you won't show anyway.

Now to display the products, it is enough to assign the Products to the DataSource of the DataGridView:

```
var productsToDisplay = this.FetchProductsToDisplay(...);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = productsToDisplay.ToList();
```

This will display the products. However, changes that the operator makes: Add / Remove / Edit rows are not updated. If you need this functionality, then the Products need to put in an object that implements [IBindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist?view=net-5.0), like (surprise!) `BindingList<Product>`:

```
private BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}
```

To Initialize the DataGridView:

```
private void DisplayProducts()
{
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(this.FetchProductsToDisplay().ToList());
}
```

Now whenever the operator makes any change to the DataGridView: Add / Remove rows, or change the Displayed values in a row, these changes are reflected in `DisplayedProducts`.

If for instance the operator clicks `Apply Now` to indicate he has finished editing the products:

```
private void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    var products = this.DisplayedProducts;
    // find out which Products are Added / Removed / Changed
    this.ProcessEditedProducts(products);
}
```

Of course you can Add / Remove / Change displayed products programmatically:

```
void AddProductsToDisplay()
{
    Product product = this.DisplayedProducts.AddNew();
    this.FillNewProduct(product);
}
```

### Back to your question

Ask yourself: Is it wise to update the database as soon as the position is changed?

If the operator starts typing, then remembers he can copy-paste items, he will stop typing, go to other controls to copy, and then continue editing the cell by pasting. Maybe he goes to other rows to look at information to decide what to put in the cell.

Another scenario: the Descriptions of Product A and Product B need to be exchanged. Think of the operator actions needed for this. When would it be wise to update the database? When are you certain that the operator is content with the new data?

Hence it is not wise to update the database as soon as a row is edited. The operator should explicitly indicate he has finished editing.

```
private void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    var products = this.DisplayedProducts;
    // find out which Products are Added / Removed / Changed
    this.ProcessEditedProducts(products);
}
```

### Further improvements

Once you've separated your data (model) from the way this data is displayed (view), using the DataSource, it is quite easy to access the Product that is displayed in the current row or in the selected rows:

```
Product CurrentProduct => (Product) this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<Product> SelectedProducts = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<Product>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Harald. You have explained it very carefully. Actually, my grid is not assigned to certain data (like product). It should be usable for various data. The configuration is loaded from an SQLite database at startup. I will try out what you propose which will take time. The idea of saving data row-wise came from MS Access. I'm just used to that. I will consider your approach.

Comment: I have tried to implement your concept but so far without success. My first problem is that the number of columns, the column names, and the data types are not known at compile time because the configuration is loaded at runtime. To try it, I have defined a class 'product' with sample data. But I haven't found out how to load the database data to the BindingList. You wrote 'Implementation is out of scope of this question.' But my question was exactly the implementation. As a beginner, I need recipes. Sorry if this doesn't value your solution.

Comment: If your question is not about DataGridView and how to display items in the DataGridView, but more about how to Fetch items from your database and how to update the database, why did you mention the DataGridView at all? It seems to me that your problem is more database related, now Winforms related. In other words: your unit tests for fetching the data from the database do not work yet.

Comment: Well, when I wrote the question I didn't know which one of the many gear wheels between the database and the DataGridView is not turning. I think I have to read more theory and then try again. Thank you anyway for spending your time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach loop.

```
private void AddInfo()
{
    // flag so we know if there was one dupe
    bool updated = false;

    // go through every row
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Purchase.Rows)
    {
        // check if there already is a row with the same id
        if (row.Cells["Pro_ID"].ToString() == txt_ProID.Text)
        {
            // update your row
            row.Cells["Purchase_Qty"] = txt_Qty.Text;

            updated = true;
            break; // no need to go any further
        }
    }

    // if not found, so it's a new one
    if (!updated)
    {
        int index = dgv_Purchase.Rows.Add();

        dgv_Purchase.Rows[index].Cells["Purchase_Qty"].Value = txt_Qty.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I cannot follow your thought. What are `txt_ProID` and `txt_Qty`? Are they textboxes? I haven't got any textboxes. Just the edited data in the DataGridView.

Comment: Thank for your reply.
Yes. They are text box.

Comment: Then it won't help. So I still need a solution to update the edited data from the DataGridView to the database.

Comment: You can use dataset in C# windows form projects.

Comment: I have replaced DataTable with DataSet[0]. This works for displaying the data. But update leads to the same error. Can you give me a line of code for the Update?